# Como puedo dar formato a la salida de la lectura de un archivo en java?

Tags: java, archivo, read

Presento el siguente problema, estoy tratando de leer un archivo .txt  en el cual tengo unos ID para una api la salida que espero deberia ser asi

tt0041951

pero al momento de leer el archivo y tratar de obtener la salida obtengo lo siguiente

t t 0 0 4 1 9 5 1

anexo mi codigo

```
public String leerArchivos() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

  int i=0;
  File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\archivos\\series.txt");
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String linea = reader.readLine();

  while (linea != null && i<4){

   linea = reader.readLine();
   System.out.println(linea);
   i++;
  }  
   return linea;
}
```

Comment: **Edit**: Puedes pasar tu variable ```linea``` por el metodo ```replace```, algo como ```linea = linea.replaceAll("\n","")```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar sigue arrojando el mismo resultado intente con replace() y replaceAll()

Comment: Disculpa, siempre me confundo con el escape de caracteres solo añade un espacio y remplazalo por nada ```replace(" ", "")```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda.. funciono